# How to dynamically populate cards content using JSON data + cardslib android library

Tags: user-interface, android, android-library, android-volley

I am very new to android programming and I am actually trying to learn how to build a very simple application to look like the Google Play store user interface.

I have found very cool android library called cardslib (https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib) that is actually doing what I would like to do more or less.

My question now is how to create cards with dynamic content from a web service instead of static image and text loading?

```
/**
 * This method builds a simple card
 */
private void initCard() {

    //Init an array of Cards
    ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        PicassoCard card = new PicassoCard(this.getActivity());
        card.setTitle("A simple card loaded with Picasso " + i);
        card.setSecondaryTitle("Simple text..." + i);
        card.setCount(i);
        cards.add(card);
    }

    CardArrayAdapter mCardArrayAdapter = new CardArrayAdapter(getActivity(), cards);

    CardListView listView = (CardListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.carddemo_extra_list_picasso);
    if (listView != null) {
        listView.setAdapter(mCardArrayAdapter);
    }

}
```

As far as I can understand from the sample code found on this project the above method is actually building an array of Cards iterating from 1 to 200. How can I make this iteration dynamic, according to the results my web service return?

My next question is how can I change the text for the Title and Secondary Title from my extracted web service?

```
 {"id":1,"sTitle":"First Entry","sSubTitle":"Subtitle
 1","sImageURL":"http://img.youtube.com/vi/u4ehZSbrl8k/default.jpg?h\u003d90\u0026w\u003d120\u0026sigh\u003d__eYg-lRy4LMjJGrDlyHy1s9yf--M\u003d"},
 {"id":2,"sTitle":"Second Entry","sSubTitle":"Subtitle
 2","sImageURL":"http://img.youtube.com/vi/TgVgni8GLqs/default.jpg?h\u003d90\u0026w\u003d120\u0026sigh\u003d__zvGG7fO4LT3ipUXfQPpA0N95Q0w\u003d"},
 {"id":3,"sTitle":"Third Entry","sSubTitle":"Subtitle
 3","sImageURL":"http://img.youtube.com/vi/pZr6y8RnX10/default.jpg?h\u003d90\u0026w\u003d120\u0026sigh\u003d__7JaAVKoYz9IR3CLgHSb1dGkKYbo\u003d"}
```

How can I modify this class in order each card created contains the above data from the web service above for example?

```
class PicassoCardThumbnail extends CardThumbnail {

    public PicassoCardThumbnail(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void setupInnerViewElements(ViewGroup parent, View viewImage) {

        /*
         * If your cardthumbnail uses external library you have to provide how to load the image.
         * If your cardthumbnail doesn't use an external library it will use a built-in method
         */

        //Here you have to set your image with an external library
        //Only for test, use a Resource Id and a Url

        //It is just an example !

        if (((PicassoCard) getParentCard()).getCount() % 2 == 0) {
            Picasso.with(getContext()).setDebugging(true);  //only for debug tests
            Picasso.with(getContext())
                    .load("https://plus.google.com/s2/photos/profile/114432517923423045208?sz=96")
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_error_loadingsmall)
                    .into((ImageView) viewImage);
        } else {
            Picasso.with(getContext()).setDebugging(true);  //only for debug tests
            Picasso.with(getContext())
                    .load(R.drawable.ic_na_img)
                    .resize(96, 96)
                    .into((ImageView) viewImage);
        }
        /*
        viewImage.getLayoutParams().width = 96;
        viewImage.getLayoutParams().height = 96;
        */
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for any pointers or help given. I am also experimenting using this great library (cardslib) along with the Volley project from Google (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/), but it is very difficult form me for now...

If someone has already managed to do it, it will much appreciated to have the opportunity to study some sample code examples.

Answer (score 3):

You could populate/update your adapter in a AsyncTask.

In your AsyncTask you can download and parse your json (in doBackground method), then you can update your adapter.

```
//Process json

ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
for (//your json elements) {
    MyCard card = new MyCard(this.getActivity());
    card.setTitle(json.getxx);
    card.setSecondaryTitle(json.getxxx);
    cards.add(card);
}


if (mCardArrayAdapter != null) {
    mCardArrayAdapter-addAll(cards);
    mCardArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

If you need more field inside your card, just use

```
publc class MyCard extends Card{

   public XXXX myField;
   //....
}
```